# VSCode: Toggle between defined texts

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have to toggle between two texts example `ABC` and `MNO` by any keyboard shortcut or mouse click.

- Like if I double click and selected word is ABC, It should be changed to MNO or vice versa.
- Or after selecting the word I can run some keyboard shortcut to toggle.
- Or if current line has `ABC` it gets changed to `MNO` with a double click or keyboard shortcut.

I know it's a very weird request but I have a use case. Any sort of work around will work even if I have to write an extension.

Comment: set a hook on the `SelectionChanged` event and monitor the selection and modify it based on your settings or hard coded rules

Comment: @rioV8 I could not find any such event, can you please help me with some link of example?

Comment: `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection()` is the eventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written an extension [Replace On](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.replace-on) that does this "immediate" replace on double click.

You can add the following to your `settings.json`

```
"replace-on.selection-changed": {
    "all": {
      "ABC": {
        "replace": "MNO",
        "literal": true,
        "immediate": true
      },
      "MNO": {
        "replace": "ABC",
        "literal": true,
        "immediate": true
      }
    },
    "javascript": {
      "foo": {
        "replace": "Bar",
        "flags": "i"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have added, for the example, that you could limit the rules for a particular languageId.

In the next version I will add the possibility to change the current "word" with the non-immediate rules by invoking a command. From command palette or key binding.

Comment: Looks great, will definitely check.

Comment: It;s working as expected but kinda does not replace, Sometimes it will only convert ABC to MNO or sometimes MNO to ABC. I guess its based on order of command registered. 
Also Can you please see if this example works:
```
{
    "Cookie": {
        "replace": "SkipCookie",
        "literal" : true,
        "immediate": true
    },
    "SkipCookie": {
        "replace": "Cookie",
        "literal": true,
        "immediate": true
    }
}
```

Comment: @anwerj It looks like it has something to do with `Overlapping ranges are not allowed!`. No the first rule that matches is used, order is not important, `SkipCookie` can always be changed to `Cookie` the other way round I did not get it. I will look into it

Comment: @anwerj Try v0.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I made an extension that does this pretty easily, see [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

This keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(Cookie)|(SkipCookie)",
    "replace": "${1:+SkipCookie}${2:+Cookie}",
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "line"
    // "matchCase": true
  }
}
```

That will perform a conditional replacement of `Cookie` with `SkipCookie` and vice versa.  Replacing all occurrences of each on the line.

[image: word toggle]

---

"Or after selecting the word I can run some keyboard shortcut to toggle."

You can make a snippet do this with a conditional replacement.  In your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+t",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(ABC)|(MNO)/${1:+MNO}${2:+ABC}/}"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
}
```

If the selected text is `ABC` it will be replaced with `MNO` and vice versa.  It will work with multiple cursors too.

`${1:+MNO}` means if there is a capture group 1, i.e., `ABC` replace it with `MNO`.

[image: snippet toggle demo]

---

This form works to toggle all occurrences in a line if you select the line first and then trigger the keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    // "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(ABC)|(MNO)/${1:+MNO}${2:+ABC}/}"
    "snippet": "${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(.*?)((ABC)|(MNO))/$1${3:+MNO}${4:+ABC}/g}"
  },
  // "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

[image: demo 2 toggling all occurrences in a line]